# jQuery Drag and Drop to highlighted boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, revert

I have this script. Well I wanted the soldier to be dropped only at the highlighted boxes.
I tried accept: $(selector) and revert: "invalid" but it seems that it disallows it to be dropped even on the un-highlighted boxes.

Comment: +1 Because it's a nice example of the droppable system. :-)

Comment: I removed the dead link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially make all droppables disabled, then during the drag start routine make `$('.cell .validmove')` droppable, and add a `revert: "invalid"` option to the draggable, so that it moves back when not put in a valid cell, if that is what you want.  Incidentally, you would probably be better having the routine you have in the `drag()` event under `start()` and reverting on `stop()`, as the `drag()` event fires continuously as you move.

```
unit.draggable({
    start: function() {
        startGrid.addClass("validmove").droppable("option", "disabled", false);
    },
    stop: function() {
        startGrid.removeClass("validmove").droppable("option", "disabled", true);
    },
    cursor: "move",
    revert: "invalid"
});
```

If you want the unit to snap to the grid, either instruct it to using the grid/snap options in `draggable()`, or add some code in the `drop()` event to animate the unit in to place.

NB. The CSS isn't working properly in Chrome, the grid does not show up, works fine in Firefox.